# How to check iPhone activation status programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, imei

I recently used the website [iphoneimei.info](http://www.iphoneimei.info/), and I was wondering if there is any way to obtain any or all of the following using Objective-C (with the IMEI and Serial Numbers):

- The iPhone's Activation status
- First and/or Most Recent activation dates
- Expiration date(s) for Support, Repairs, & Service coverage
- The iPhone's firmware version
- If the SIM card is locked (if the iPhone has one)

I am already aware of the fact that getting the IMEI (and Serial) numbers is not possible, at least on the latest iOS versions and devices, so if there is any way to programmatically obtain the following information, please let me know.

Also, if this is not possible in objective-c, but rather in another language, please let me know. My base goal is to understand how online services (like [iphoneimei.info](http://www.iphoneimei.info/)) work, and what enables them to obtain their information (that is, specifically to do with the code).

Comment: You can use Career Telephony Framework , it might help you .

Comment: @iphonedev7 : Did you eventually find a way to get the activation date?